# Cleanly hard code a pandas dataframe into a python script?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is there a good clean way to hard code a pandas dataframe into python code (e.g. a .py file)?

I don't want to store in a separate CSV (I want the script file to be able to run on it's own), and the dataframe is not very big. I also want it clear in the code what it is and easily modifiable.

For example:

```
    cols = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
    rows = ['red', 'blue', 'green','orange','pink']
    data = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0], [10.0,11.0,12.0],[13.0, 14.0,15.0]]
    pd.DataFrame(data, index=rows, columns=cols)
```

This works ok, but if you want to modify, say, green val2, it's not easy to immediately find the right value. Slightly better (in some ways):

```
    cols = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
    rows = ['red', 'blue', 'green','orange','pink']
    data = [
    #  val1,  val2, val3
        [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],   # red
        [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],   # blue
        [7.0, 8.0, 9.0],   # green
        [10.0,11.0,12.0],  # orange
        [13.0, 14.0,15.0]] # pink
    pd.DataFrame(data, index=rows, columns=cols)
```

but this requires a lot of manual formatting, or writing a separate dataframe printer, and is ugly and hackish.

Comment: Put the csv into your file as a string

Comment: @MadPhysicist don't forget to use `io.StringIO` in that case :)

Comment: @r.ook. Yes you do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.read_csv` based on a string literal:

```
try: from io import StringIO  # Python 3
except: from StringIO import StringIO  # Python 2

import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = u"""\
    val1, val2, val3,   color
     1.0,  2.0,  3.0,   red
     4.0,  5.0,  6.0,   blue
     7.0,  8.0,  9.0,   green
    10.0, 11.0, 12.0,   orange
    13.0, 14.0, 15.0,   pink
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(TESTDATA), index_col=-1, sep=r",\s*", engine='python')
print(df)

# prints:
#         val1  val2  val3
# color                   
# red      1.0   2.0   3.0
# blue     4.0   5.0   6.0
# green    7.0   8.0   9.0
# orange  10.0  11.0  12.0
# pink    13.0  14.0  15.0
```

The inclusion of `\s*` in `sep` means that you then have the *option* to pretty-format your data with whitespace. Since you say the dataframe is not very big, why not do that, for the sake of readability? But if you're averse to manually aligning things even for a small dataframe, you could just remove the spaces and paste the raw CSV content in `TESTDATA`. Then you can drop the `\s*` out of `sep` and remove `engine='python'` (the latter is only there to suppress a warning associated with the use of regular expressions in `sep`).

An even better version, which allows you to use the `print(df)` output itself as the input, without manual editing, would be:

```
try: from io import StringIO  # Python 3
except: from StringIO import StringIO  # Python 2

import pandas as pd 

TESTDATA = u"""\
            val1  val2  val3
    color                   
    red      1.0   2.0   3.0
    blue     4.0   5.0   6.0
    green    7.0   8.0   9.0
    orange  10.0  11.0  12.0
    pink    13.0  14.0  15.0
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(TESTDATA), index_col=0, sep=r"\s+", engine='python')
print(df)
```

Comment: I would separate the data from the StringIO creation and put the index in the beginning, like it's generally supposed to be, but +1 regardless

Comment: This works pretty well. I also just used `print(df)` on the source dataframe for an easy to copy string to use with this, which avoided any manual formatting.

Comment: @argentum2f  OK, let me add a version of the solution that allows unedited re-use of the `print(df)` output

Answer (score 1):

To provide a complete answer based on our comments:

```
from io import StringIO

data = """
col1,col2,col3
a,b,c
d,e,f
"""

s = StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(s)
```

result:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    b    c
1    d    e    f
```